# Developer Studio BPEL project doesn't recognize analytics extension

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, wso2-business-process

Using wso2bps-3.5.1, wso2das-3.0.1 and Developer Studio 3.8.0

I'm following a guideline for [Monitoring a BPEL Process with WSO2 DAS](https://docs.wso2.com/display/BPS351/Monitoring+a+BPEL+Process+with+WSO2+DAS). I recieve this from inside Developer Studio and my .bpel file:

*Error: Extension "http://wso2.org/bps/monitoring/publisher" is not supported by this implementation.*

```
<bpel:extensions>
    <bpel:extension namespace="http://wso2.org/bps/monitoring/publisher" mustUnderstand="yes"/> 
</bpel:extensions>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 Developer Studio uses Eclipse bpel plugin to add support for bpel creation for WSO2 BPS. This BAM publishing bpel extension activity that you are referring to, is a custom extension developed by WSO2 and default bpel editor is not aware of this extension. This is why it gives syntax errors when you add this extension activity from the source view.

However, you should be able to export and deploy the CAR file without any issues regardless of the syntax errors.

According to [this](https://eclipse.org/bpel/users/pdf/CreateAnExtensionActivity.pdf), there's a possibility to add support for custom extension activities in bpel editor.

Hence, I have raised a [jira](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/DEVTOOLBPS-22) in WSO2 BPS Tooling jira for this feature.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep an eye on your Jira ticket